# Python precedence 1 < 0 == 0 --> False

Tags: python, boolean, operator-precedence

Why this expression evaluates to False.
`print(1 < 0 == 0)`

You would think that the expression on the left is evaluated first and then the expression on the right, thus returning True

Thanks!!

Comment: There is no precedence. Python is one of few languages that allows you to assert multiple relations like is common in mathematics: e.g. `1 < x < 10` is true when `1 < x and x < 10`. In your example, `1 < 0` is false, which makes the entire expression false.

Comment: However, the three subexpressions are evaluated left-to-right, if it matters. You can prove it with `a = ""; (a:=a+"1") < (a:=a+"2") < (a:=a+"3")`: `a` will be `"123"`.